# The full asm code for ENTRY(int3)

Tags: linux, kernel

Currently, I want to hook the x86-32 int3 handler in Linux-3.13.1 kernel.

Firstly, I check the asm code in the entry_32.S

I found the related code is as follows:

```
ENTRY(int3)
    RING0_INT_FRAME
    ASM_CLAC
    pushl_cfi $-1           # mark this as an int
    SAVE_ALL
    TRACE_IRQS_OFF
    xorl %edx,%edx      # zero error code
    movl %esp,%eax      # pt_regs pointer
    call do_int3
    jmp ret_from_exception
    CFI_ENDPROC
END(int3)
```

Then, I write a kernel module to hook this ENTRY(int3) as follows:

```
#define SAVE_ALL \
         "pushl %%eax\n\t" \
         "pushl %%ebp\n\t" \
         "pushl %%edi\n\t" \
         "pushl %%esi\n\t" \
         "pushl %%edx\n\t" \
         "pushl %%ecx\n\t" \
         "pushl %%ebx\n\t" \

//get the addr from the system.map

unsigned long ret_from_exception=0xc1642fc0;
unsigned long do_int3=0xc1643c70;

   __asm__  (
   ...
   "go_here:                                \n\t"
      "pushl $-1                            \n\t"
      SAVE_ALL
      "xorl %%edx,%%edx                     \n\t"
      "movl %%esp,%%eax                     \n\t"
      "call *do_int3                        \n\t"
      "jmp *ret_from_exception              \n\t"
   :: );
}
```

Unfortunately, the kernel module failed to work.

```
[ 5359.750705] task: e9095a90 ti: e809a000 task.ti: e809a000
[ 5359.750709] EIP: 0060:[<c1645686>] EFLAGS: 00010046 CPU: 0
[ 5359.750717] EIP is at kprobe_exceptions_notify+0xf6/0x460
[ 5359.750720] EAX: 00000000 EBX: 0000007b ECX: 00000000 EDX: 0000007a
[ 5359.750723] ESI: e809bfc4 EDI: c1a4f100 EBP: e809bf58 ESP: e809bf30
[ 5359.750726]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 5359.750729] CR0: 8004003b CR2: b76806c0 CR3: 2a944000 CR4: 000007f0
[ 5359.750731] Stack:
[ 5359.750733]  00000000 ea0880b6 000004df c1a54400 0000007a c1a54400 f7b84400 c1909a88
[ 5359.750741]  00000000 c190c328 e809bf74 c1646be5 e809bf8c 00000002 e809bfc4 00000000
[ 5359.750748]  00000000 e809bf84 c1646c52 fffffffe 00000000 e809bfa0 c1646c8d e809bfc4
[ 5359.750755] Call Trace:
[ 5359.750763]  [<c1646be5>] notifier_call_chain+0x45/0x60
[ 5359.750768]  [<c1646c52>] atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x22/0x30
[ 5359.750773]  [<c1646c8d>] notify_die+0x2d/0x30
[ 5359.750777]  [<c1643cf4>] do_int3+0x84/0x100
```

I think the ENTRY(int3) asm transfer may not be correct.

How can I transfer the macro RING0_INT_FRAM ASM_CLAC to the ASM code?